# How to fix buffer selection issue in ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API and LGIM applications

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry, buffer

I had strange LGIM application behavior where the map spatial search did not highlighted the parcels within the Geometry Buffer. What could be the possible reasons?

[image: Geometry Buffer Selection Issue]

LGIM stands for the Local Government Information Model. It is a geodatabase schema ESRI uses to support the ArcGIS JavaScript applications they have.

Comment: if you could post the code from your application specific to the spatial search, it might help us narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The LGIM data supporting the application is possible issue.

LOWERPARCELID field in the ParcelPublishing dataset, TaxParcel Feature Class must not have  records.
The Geometry Buffer Selection functionality uses the LOWERPARCELID to execute.  records there will break it.

[image: ParcelPublishing.TaxParcel.LOWTARCELID]